# Deleting duplicate records where concat of 3 column are same in mysql?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table of more than 800,000 records. There are 8 columns per row. I need to delete duplicates of records i.e where column1 and column2 and column5 are same. All of the columns should be the same.

For example

---

Column1 |  Column2 |     .... | column5

---

John    |  Eng     |   ....   | Pass

Alex    |  Eng     |   ....   | Pass

John    |  Chemistry|   ....   | Pass

John    |  Eng     |   ....   | Pass

---

I want to delete 1 and last record. ( i.e john+Eng+Pass)

Answer (score 1):

Lets supose that your table is named `t` and t's primary key is `pk`.

I suggest to you do the work in 2 steps:

First step: **Identify rows to delete**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE to_delete AS 
select distinct
     t2.pk
from
     t t1
inner join
     t t2
where
     t1.c1 = t2.c1 and 
     t1.c2 = t2.c2 and 
     t1.c5 = t2.c5 and
     t2.pk > t1.pk      #erase this line to
                        #delete all dups rows
```

Second step: **Delete rows**

```
delete from t
where t.pk in (select pk from to_delete )
```

Simplified sample ad sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f97da/3/0

Disclaimer: delete rows over your risk.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Query:

```
create table abc (id int(11) primary key auto_increment, col_1 varchar(255), 
col_2 varchar(255), col_3 varchar(255));

insert into abc (col_1, col_2, col_3) values ('a', 'a', 'a'),
('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a','a', 'a'), ('b','b','b'),('a','b','c');

DELETE a1.* from abc a1 inner join abc a2 ON a1.col_1 = a2.col_1 
AND a1.col_2 = a2.col_2 AND a1.col_3 = a2.col_3 AND a1.id <> a2.id;
```

SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08e4b/1